# How to Update Group Rows With cursor (Row by Row)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, database-cursor

| Store | Product | BeginQty | ReceiptQty | SaleQty | EndQty | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 100 | 0 | 30 | 80 | 2020-10-21 |
| 1 | A | -- | 100 | 30 | -- | 2020-10-23 |
| 2 | B | 150 | 150 | 50 | 250 | 2020-10-21 |
| 2 | B | -- | 0 | 20 | -- | 2020-10-22 |
| 2 | B | -- | 0 | 30 | -- | 2020-10-24 |

How to Update Next Rows (--)?
result

| Store | Product | BeginQty | ReceiptQty | SaleQty | EndQty | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 100 | 0 | 30 | 80 | 2020-10-21 |
| 1 | A | 80 | 100 | 30 | 150 | 2020-10-23 |
| 2 | B | 150 | 150 | 50 | 250 | 2020-10-21 |
| 2 | B | 250 | 0 | 50 | 200 | 2020-10-22 |
| 2 | B | 200 | 0 | 40 | 160 | 2020-10-24 |

BeginQty + ReceiptQty - SaleQty = EndQty
Date 2020-10-21 has complete data

Comment: What research have you done? What have you tried? Where did you get stuck? And why do you require a cursor? Thats terrible for performance.

Comment: Please explain how "80" is calculated for the end quantity on the first row.

Answer (score 1):

You can use analytical function as follows:

```
select Store, Product,
       sum(BeginQty + ReceiptQty - SaleQty) over (partition by store, product order by date) - ReceiptQty + SaleQty as BeginQty,
       ReceiptQty, SaleQty,
       sum(BeginQty + ReceiptQty - SaleQty) over (partition by store, product order by date) as EndQty,
       Date
  from your_Table
```

Answer (score 0):

You would not use a cursor for this.  In fact, the general rule is *avoid cursors* whenever you can.  If you have a problem that you think needs a cursor, then push back.  Okay, sometimes they are useful . . . the canonical case is when you need to call a stored procedure on each row.  That is pretty much it.

Your case has very specific rules around the dates.  And I note that the first `endqty` doesn't match the arithmetic you have specified.  So:

```
with toupdate as (
      select t.*,
             max(case when date = '2020-10-21' then endqty end) over (partition by store, product) as first_endqty,
             sum(case when date <> '2020-10-21' then ReceiptQty - SaleQty else 0 end) over (partition by store, product order by date) as inc
      from t
     )
update toupdate
    set endqty = first_endqty + inc,
        beginqty = first_endqty + inc - (ReceiptQty - SaleQty)
    where date <> '2020-10-21';
```